# Wordpress restrict access to URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Hey im trying to dynamically (depending on post-id, regex pattern etc.) restrict access to URLs. Mainly those who points to attachments.
I tried to hook on the *parse_request* hook but it does not get fired when the URL is directly entered in the browser (e.g. example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/test.txt)

Is there any hook that gets fired when accessing an URL directly or another way to programmatically restrict access to an URL?

Thanks
EmKo

Comment: When you access a non-php file directly like that, PHP isn't involved. It doesn't go through Wordpress at all. The web server just fetches that file and returns it to the client directly. I'm not sure how to best  do this in WP.

Comment: Hello EmKo, a possible approach to your request would be to create a plugin and use the built-in wordpress functions to access the URLs the way you want to. But please make sure to give us more information on what you are trying to achieve cause to be honest I dont think I got the point of your problem.

Comment: Makes sense. Many Thanks. I'm trying a different approach.

Comment: Hey Jameu,
i try to write a plugin that generates links that are valid for a specific period of time.
Something like that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237458/how-to-generate-expiring-url
It works but when accessing the URL directly the file is loaded anyway.
My approach was to monitor the requested URLs and take action when an URL should be restricted.